# Python - wxGrid.DeleteCols() : Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, wxpython, segmentation-fault

I am working with xyPython, specifically a `wx.Grid` and when I attempt to delete a column from the grid the program crashes and terminal says "Segmentation Error"

```
dataGrid.CreateGrid(30, 20)
```

...

```
dataGrid.DeleteCols()
```

That is pretty much the code.  I can delete rows, just not columns.
If I remove the delete column line it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the following thread, you may have to set the column labels yourself or you could get an error:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/wxpython-users/IpARv4wVoqw

Then in this newer thread, it's said that you may have to call IncRef: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/wxpython-users/I1kndNvIEEQ

Comment: Thanks so much for putting me on to .IncRef() , it completly solved my problems. 

Like explained here: [link](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/wx-grid-and-IncRef-td5713865.html)   
Every time I used SetColAttr(),  
'dataGrid.SetColAttr(column, textFormatAttr)'  
the line prior to that, I needed to call .IncRef()  
'textFormatAttr.IncRef()'  
so..  
'textFormatAttr.IncRef()  
dataGrid.SetColAttr(column, textFormatAttr)'  
And yes, It seems I will have to rename the colums every time I delete a row, not really a problem.  
Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.grid.Grid-class.html

there are parameters for `DeleteCols(self, pos, numCols, updateLabels)`